# Getting 'Syntax Error' on jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying a simple chat application using simple jade view engine with express. When I run my app I am getting syntax error on following view code. But it is as simple as that.

```
    extends layout
    block scripts
      script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
      script(type='text/javascript')
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('chat', function(data) {
          document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = '<p><b>' + data.title + '</b>: ' +   data.contents + '</p>';
        });

        var submitChat = function(form) {
          socket.emit('chat', {text: form.chat.value});
          return false;
        };
    block content
     div#chat
      form(onsubmit='return submitChat(this);')
        input#chat(name='chat', type='text')
        input(type='submit', value='Send Chat')
```

I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: views/chat.jade:9 
7| document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = 
8| '<p><b>' + data.title + '</b>: ' + data.contents + '</p>'; > 
9| }); 
10| var submitChat = function(form) { 
11| socket.emit('chat', {text: form.chat.value}); 
12| return false; 
Unexpected token ; at Function (<anonymous>) at assertExpression
```

Comment: If you want really someone to debug your code, please post the real code you have... and please, format your question properly.

Comment: form(onsubmit='return submitChat(this)') try removing ; from this line

Comment: No. nothing happen. It is valid syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you missed a simple **dot** here, see [Jade Reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#blockinatag).

For example:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

will give

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <var>socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');</var>
</script>
```

and you get your `Unexpected token` error.

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

To show you the difference in an example, this code from above will give:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
</script>
```

So your code should look like:

```
extends layout
block scripts
  script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
  script(type='text/javascript').
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
      document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = '<p><b>' + data.title + '</b>: ' +   data.contents + '</p>';
    });

    var submitChat = function(form) {
      socket.emit('chat', {text: form.chat.value});
      return false;
    };
block content
 div#chat
  form(onsubmit='return submitChat(this);')
    input#chat(name='chat', type='text')
    input(type='submit', value='Send Chat')
```

Comment: I wish I can give more up votes, very detailed answer to explain the subtle mistake.